# Is there a way I can filter values of two tables in PowerBI and then do aggregation such as getting the percentages/ratio

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, m

I am working on PowerBI and I have two tables like this:

Table-1: This table shows the number of schools visited in a certain month

| School | Chiefdom | District | School Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S-1 | Ch-1 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-2 | Ch-2 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-3 | Ch-2 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-4 | Ch-3 | D-2 | ST-1 |
| S-5 | Ch-2 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-6 | Ch-1 | D-1 | ST-1 |

Table-2: This table shows the total number of schools

| School | Chiefdom | District | School Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S-1 | Ch-1 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-2 | Ch-2 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-3 | Ch-2 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-4 | Ch-3 | D-2 | ST-1 |
| S-5 | Ch-2 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-6 | Ch-1 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-7 | Ch-1 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-8 | Ch-2 | D-1 | ST-1 |
| S-9 | Ch-4 | D-2 | ST-1 |
| S-10 | Ch-4 | D-2 | ST-1 |
| S-11 | Ch-5 | D-2 | ST-1 |
| S-12 | Ch-3 | D-2 | ST-1 |

My goal: I ought to get a percentage of schools not visited per chiefdom from the above two tables. The idea is to filter by each chiefdom in both tables, then subtract each filtered chiefdom in table 1 from the same in table 2, and get percentage of schools not visited. I tried something like this but the results do not add up. How do you think I should tackle this?

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE (
     1 - COUNT(Table1[chiefdom]) /  COUNT(Table2[chiefdom])
)
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a Cheifdom dimension table to filter both of your data tables via a relationship? This will make the end-product a lot simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

FILTER() returns a table object, so use **COUNTROWS**(FILTER()) instead of COUNT(FILTER())

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Measure:

```
Percentage of schools not visited =
CALCULATE (
1 - COUNT(FILTER(Table1, Table1[chiefdom] = Table2[chiefdom])) /  COUNT(FILTER(Table2, Table1[chiefdom] = Table2[chiefdom]))
)

Result:

Percentage of schools not visited = 1 - 3 / 6 = 0.5 = 50%

This means that 50% of the schools in the chiefdom are not visited.
```

Comment: Thanks Kadam for the response. I however get this error with the above solution ```The COUNT function only accepts a column reference as an argument.```